# Использование точки вместо двоеточия

Tags: пунктуация

Можно ли после "Сообщаем следующее" поставить точку и далее текст отразить в новом предложении.

Answer (score 1):

Нет, не стоит. Будет обованное предложение. Если не хотите ставить двоеточие, можно написать так: "Доводим до Вашего сведения, что..."

Comment: Может, дел не в двоеточии, а в слишком длинном предложении. Если сообщается много чего (и, возможно в виде нескольких пунктов).

Answer (score 1):

*Что-то вопросы стали всплывать древние...*

Я думаю, тут такое вполне возможно ради оформления. 
Если стоит точка, то всё дальнейшее можно считать сообщаем, а при двоеточии - только до следующей точки, это далеко не всегда то, что хочет передать пишущий.

Если это "на ваш запрос №.... сообщаем, " фактически весь текст письма будет состоять из этого "сообщаем". Ну и как его уложить в одну фразу?

В конце концов можно написать *Сообщаем нижеследующее*. Хотя немного канцеляритом отдает, но уж самый жестокий формалист не придерется.